# Changing static content directory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, express

I am trying to set the express.static path to something different based on a session variable.  The relevant code is below.

```
app.use( '/', function(req, res, next ) {

    if ( req.session.loggedIn ) {
        console.log("loggedIn :  " + req.session.loggedIn);
        app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/private'));
        next();
    }
    else {
        console.log("not logged in.");
        app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        next();
    }

 });
```

When I start the application, I begin with not having req.session.loggedIn set.  So it will use the static content in the /public directory (which contains an angular powered application for public users.)  I then do a login (code below)

```
app.post('/login', function( req, res ) {

    req.session.loggedIn = true;
    var message = {};
    message.success = true;
    message.text = "Logging you in...";
    res.json(message);

});
```

Which sets the req.session.loggedIn variable to be true.  I then hit refresh on the page (and have tried hard refresh, and cache clear/refresh as well).  The console.log tells me "loggedIn : true" as expected, however it does NOT load the static content from the /private directory.  It instead continues to load from the /public directory.

Can anyone shed light on this issue?

Comment: Further research has given me more information but not a solution.  I think that what is happening is that my code is simply adding the /private directory for static content to the app stack, but since the /public one was already there, it will just always hit that one first.  Not sure what to do about that though if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The express.static is just another middleware so you can call it directly with the request and response parameters. Instead of adding it to the '/' route directly you could wrap it in another middleware like this:

```
var public_pages = express.static(__dirname + '/public');
var private_pages = express.static(__dirname + '/private');

app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session.loggedIn == 1) {
        private_pages(req, res, next);
    } else {
        public_pages(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

Comment: What I am more specifically trying to do though is to change the "/" path to use a different directory at some point in the application flow.  So to begin with I will be using /public and then the login variable will be set and I want it to use /private.  But what I'm finding is that calling express.static after I have set the login simply adds /private to the application stack instead of replacing the /public one as I'd like.

Comment: @user3590712 this exactly what my answer allows you to do. What part of it did not work for you?

Comment: In my case that isn't working.  The reason is that I am calling express with only one page the index.html.  When I load up the app first, it will go to /public.  After I set the loggedIn variable, it will now add /private to the application stack.  This means that if a page is not found in /public it will go to /private.  However I am loading index.html which exists in /public and also /private.  Since /public was added first via the static call, it will never try to goto the /private directory, because the /public static call is still in place.

Comment: @user3590712 in my proposed solution, the static middleware is not added to the router. Both static middleware are saved in variables and then called appropriately by the middleware that is added via the app.use function. I've tested it with index.html in both public and private folders and it works. Have you tried my solution yet? If yes, the problem might be elsewhere, the browser's cache perhaps.